# How to enable save as dialogue box in chrome web driver using selenium-python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-testing, webautomation

So the default settings of my chrome has "ask where to save downloads" turned off. I would like it to be turned on automatically using Selenium-python so that I can change the name and directory of the file but don't know how to modify the settings on web driver start up. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: maybe it will be better to set automatically the downloads to some custom folder you will use inside the driver settings?

Comment: The thing is, I am downloading multiple files at the same time and each file has to go to a respective folder and I don't want to relaunch the webdriver with different settings every time i do that. Furthermore, I cant even use OS commands to rename and relocate files because the files names are variably automatically generated and include the date and time at which each file was downloaded so I might end up with 9 files having the same name because they were downloaded at the same time and 1 file for example that was downloaded a minute after.

Comment: Well, I see... Let's see if someone will have a solution in this way.